# MySQL user with empty hostname

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.6

On a MySQL 5.6 server, the `mysql.user` table contains an user with an empty hostname (`'jdoe'@''`). What does that mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User whose name is joe can connect from any host.

Please note what [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127)

[image]

say in its bulletpoints on Page 498 Paragraph 6:

> On Unix, MySQL comes with a mysql_secure_installation script that can
>   perform several helpful security-related operations on your
>   installation. The script has the following capabilities:
>
> - Set a password for the root accounts
> - Remove any remotely accessible root accounts.
> - **Remove the anonymous user accounts. This improves security because
>     it prevents the possibility of anyone connecting to the MySQL server
>     as root from a remote host. The results is that anyone who wants to
>     connect as root must first be able to log in on the server host, which
>     provides an additional barrier against attack**.
> - Remove the test database (If you remove the anonymous accounts, you
>     might also want to remove the test database to which they have
>     access).

That user needs to be removed immediately.

Simply run

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE host='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

## UPDATE 2017-02-01 17:07 EST

According to the MySQL Documentation on [Access Control, Stage 2: Request Verification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/request-access.html)

> A '%' or blank Host value means “any host.”

This is applicable at all levels of grants.

Answer (score -3):

That's the solution, delete all users where host='';
I had user PUBLIC@%  and couldn't remove it. Never saw this in prior versions of mariadb.
Not sure why this latest version of Mariadb stuck that in there on install, but I was pulling my hair out to remove it. Thanks much.

Comment: Do you mind reorganising your post so its a record of a solution. At the moment it reads like a rant.

Comment: I'm trying to help people as you sit there criticizing my syntax and grammar. Get a life.